# Excel VBA AutoFilter Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

When I record the macro I get the following:

```
Range("A2:Z74").AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$Z$74").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
```

But when I run this macro, I get error

```
1004 This can't be applied to the selected range. Select a single cell in a range and try again.Select a single cell in a range and try again.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: "Select a single cell in a range and try again."?

Comment: I can't remember off the top of my head, but there are about 3 or 4 methods/properties dealing with auto filters that always need to be used in conjuction with each other.  It's a very messy bit of the API.

Comment: I already tried putting in just one cell reference and that still did not work. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Apparently the idea has to do with running the code in ThisWorkbook opposed to in a Module. Is there any way to run this in ThisWorkbook rather than needing to go through a module? I ran it in a module and it runs fine but I'd rather not put this block of code in a module.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
With .Range("A1", .Cells(.rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp))
         .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"

    End with
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case I can help people in the future,

I had the same error occur when the range I selected was empty. After I corrected the range to cover cells with drop-downs in them the error stopped occurring.